# Find the prime numbers $p, q$ satisfying perfect square

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, square-numbers

> Find the prime numbers $p, q$ satisfy: $p^2+3pq+q^2+6q+6p-60$ is perfect square

**My try:** $p^2+2pq+q^2+6q+6p+9+pq-69=r^2$ so $pq-69=(r-q-p-3)(r+p+q+3)$ and I stuck here, any hint please. Thank you.

Comment: Well, I did a quick search with Mathematica (using the bounds $2\le\text{p}\le10^4$ and $2\le\text{q}\le10^4$) and found: $\left(\text{p},\text{q}\right)\in\left\{\left(2,3\right),\left(3,2\right),\left(3,7\right),\left(3,23\right),\left(7,3\right),\left(23,3\right)\right\}$

Comment: Thank you, I only know $(p,q) = {(2,3),(3,2)}$

Comment: @JanEerland I'll just put up a thought that struck me... maybe you can clarify it for me? Why not take $s = p + q, m = pq$ and rewrite the equation as $s(s+6) + m = r^2 + 60$ and solve??  I'd like to know if this way of solving would end up being a lot more difficult...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression is

$$p^2+3pq+q^2+6q+6p-60 = r^2 \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Using modulo $3$, we get

$$p^2 + q^2 \equiv r^2 \pmod{3} \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

Since perfect squares are congruent to $0$ or $1$ modulo $3$, if both $p$ and $q$ were not $3$, then the left side of \eqref{eq2A} would be congruent to $2$ modulo $3$. Thus, at least one of them must be $3$. Due to the symmetry between $p$ and $q$ in \eqref{eq1A}, WLOG have $p = 3$. Next, multiply both sides by $4$ to get

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
4r^2 & = 36 + 36q + 4q^2 + 24q + 72 - 240 \\
& = 4q^2 + 60q - 132 \\
& = 4q^2 + 60q + 225 - 225 - 132 \\
& = (2q + 15)^2 - 357
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

This leads to

$$(2q + 15)^2 - (2r)^2 = 357 \; \to \; (2q + 15 - 2r)(2q + 15 + 2r) = 3(7)(17) \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

To check the various factor possibilities (note since $2q + 15 + 2r \gt 0$, they'll both be positive), we have

$$2q + 15 - 2r = f_1 \tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$
$$2q + 15 + 2r = f_2 \tag{6}\label{eq6A}$$

with $f_1 f_2 = 357$, $f_1 \lt f_2$ and $f_1, f_2 \in \{1, 3, 7, 17, 21, 51, 119, 357\}$. Adding \eqref{eq5A} and \eqref{eq6A} gives

$$4q + 30 = f_1 + f_2 \; \; \to \; \; q = \frac{f_1 + f_2 - 30}{4} \tag{7}\label{eq7A}$$

This gives $q = \frac{1 + 357 - 30}{4} = 82$, $q = \frac{3 + 119 - 30}{4} = 23$, $q = \frac{7 + 51 - 30}{4} = 7$ or $q = \frac{17 + 21 - 30}{4} = 2$. Since only $2$, $7$ and $23$ are prime (with corresponding $r$ values of $1$, $11$ and $29$) then, along with switching $p$ and $q$ around, results in what [Jan Eerland](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/226665/jan-eerland)'s question [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4377776/find-the-prime-numbers-p-q-satisfying-perfect-square#comment9149119_4377776) indicates, i.e.,

$$(p, q) \in \{(3,2),(2,3),(3,7),(7,3),(3,23),(23,3)\} \tag{8}\label{eq8A}$$